# Deep linking in facebook without dialog

Tags: android, facebook, dialog, single-sign-on, deep-linking

I have created AppLinkingHowTo project by using following facebook documentation of deep linking

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/link-to-your-native-app/

its working fine but when click on share button a dialog is appear.I dont want this dialog.I have implemented single sign on and i want on click button if user login then it will directly share message on Facebook without showing the dialog.how to do this..

UPDATE:I am creating an app to implement deeplinking.the concept of deeplinking is that we share any message from our application on facebook wall then we open facebook native application installed in our device and click on that post which we have share from our application so it will open the application if our application is installed and if application not install it will open the browser.

I have implementing deep linking by using above link.it is the facebook document.

here a dialog is generated to share our post and when i click on this post from fb native app it will open application if it install other wise browser.

but the problem is i dont want this dialog.I am able to post my message on facebook without dialog by this request

```
res = facebook.request("me/feed", params, "POST");
```

but when i click on on post from fb native app it will not open my application and open the browser.

is deeplinking is possible without open this dialog or can we edit this dialog,if yes,then how to edit it.

Comment: I tried the same thing in my app, but It never worked, I posted this questions in several blogs and forums, no one gave correct answer. And Now I am very sure that its not possible to make a deeplinking post without using the default dialog, and here is the interesting thing, u cannot even change the look and feel of that dialog accept your message and the logo....

Comment: I can confirm this bug.  Deep linking only works when posted via the dialog.  However OpenGraph posts made without the dialog also show good deeplinking, the only issue is feed posts.